# Display Templates successfully uploaded but don't show in Search Result Edit web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a ready and tested (on a different site: and it worked perfectly) Display template (made up of 2 HTML files)

This morning I was trying to upload the same Display template in the:

```
/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Search
```

directory of a different site. First I was getting a 'You don't have access' message. The reason seemed to be because of 'Scripting Capabilities' being turned off by default for the root site collection in Office 365.

[See Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&=amp&rs=en-US&ad=US)

So, we turned this on. It says that it takes 24 hours to take effect, but after around 5 hours I tried again and it let me upload, and I thought that for this reason it must have taken effect (this might not be the case as you will see).

When going into the Search redirection page and trying to edit the Search Result web part, under the Display Templates section, only the Default Results Control Display Template is being shown.

This is what I want to achieve and the same thing that I managed on a different site:

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuqYN.jpg)

I have no idea why. My only explanation would be that it's not fully functional because the 24 hours have not passed yet. Could this be the case?

I would appreciate any insight regarding this from experienced users.

Comment: are the files checked in, published, and approved?

Comment: How do you know? With regards to 'checked in', I think so as there is the option to 'Check out'. With regards to the others, nothing suggests otherwise, but still, I dont know where to check

Comment: Ok so I found the option to 'Publish' and it says this: http://imgur.com/z1dLI3U

Does it mean that I can upload files, but can't publish them and approve them?

Comment: Apparently not. In the Master Pages of the site where this process worked perfectly, the publish/unpublish/approve/reject/cancel approval buttons are all grayed out too. So, unless on this site, somehow, uploaded files are automatically published and approved, the files being unpublished does not seem to be the problem.